# planets positions using css and javascript?

Tags: javascript

I made several classic php/javascript/css web pages, so some basic knowledge is here, but now I need to create an astrological page with planets positions at a certain date and time.

Planets positions should be displayed graphically by two circles, one inside of the other.

Both circles are divided into 12 houses (30 degrees).

Inner circle should display planets positions of a certain date and time (birthday), and outer circle should display current planets positions (planetary transits).

I suppose that I need some source of swiss ephemerides in some readible format (maybe xml or json ?).

Is it possible to do using javascript and maybe html canvas ?

I need some general instructions - where to start, and what could be the shortest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: you can achieve what you want using `canvas` or `svg` also you need to use objects to store the data for the planets and act accordingly

Comment: @AminJafari, objects - do you mean classes ?

Comment: I'm talking about js, it doesn't have classes as in Object Oriented languages, so basically yeah objects

Comment: @AminJafari http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: but it says it is available since ECMAScript 6, which currently has very limited browser support

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to create two arrays containg the planets.
One array with the planets for the inner circle (time / date) and one for the outer (position).

The outer circle is the easiest I guess. With each planet, store the position which could be an angle in radians on the circle. For example:

```
var outerPlanets = [
    { name: 'planet one', position: 0.2},
    { name: 'planet two', position: 1.3}
];
```

The inner circle could be tricky, since it depends on a date/time. But one way is to say (again, for example) 0 degrees on the circle is the beginning of time. 360 degrees is now.

Let's say the beginning of time is 0, now is 2000 and a planet's birthday was on 1200.That means it should be positioned on (1200/2000)*100% = 60% on the circle, which is (360/100)*60 = 216 degrees.

```
var innerPlanets = [
    { name: 'planet three', birthday: 1200},
    { name: 'planet four', birthday: 1800}
];
```

With that information, you could loop over the arrays, and draw each planet on a canvas.

```
var circleCenterX = 500;
var circleCenterY = 500;

var circleInnerRadius = 200;

var planetX = circleCenterX + (Math.cos(planet.angle) * circleInnerRadius);
var planetY = circleCenterY + (Math.sin(planet.angle) * circleInnerRadius);
```

A thing to note: angles on canvas are in radians, not in degrees:

```
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI)
```

Comment: Pimmol, thanks a lot for the idea, and especially for your code. I will try (tonight) and I'll  write here my experience.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. If you have a visual of what you want to achieve I maybe can help you better